# Find all primes of the form $2^{2^n} + 5$ for a nonnegative integer n

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

I'm a little lost on how to do this problem. It looks a lot like the definition for the Fermat numbers: $F_n = 2^{2^n} + 1$, however I'm not sure how to use that in order to find all of the primes of the form: $2^{2^n} + 5$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Look at $2^{2^n} + 5$ modulo $3$ for $n \geq 1$.

I got this hint by factoring $2^{2^n}+5$ for the first few values of $n$ using the `sage` command `[factor(2^(2^n)+5) for n in range(6)]`. When in doubt, experiment!

Answer (score 4):

$$
2^{2^1}=2^2 \equiv_3 1
$$
$$
2^{2^2}=(2^2)^2 \equiv_3 1
$$
$$
\dots
$$
$$
2^{2^n}=(2^{2^{n-1}})^2 \equiv_3 1
$$

Comment: Is $\equiv_3$ a 'standard' way of notation? I'd really like that since I am getting tired of writing $\mod 3$ each time=)

Comment: not sure how standard it is, but it's pretty self-explanatory, and anything that saves on saccadic eye-movements reduces the mental cost of parsing an expression

Comment: Well then, lets make it standard!